# How to lock a file under local workspace via TFS 2012 API

Tags: c#, api, tfs, locking, workspace

I am attempting to check-out a single file via `workspace.PendEdit` with an exclusive lock `LockLevel.CheckOut`. The following function succeeds (no errors) but it seems to have no effect on the file in TFS (not checked-out and no lock).

```
public static void Lock(string filePath)
    {
        var workspace = GetWorkspace(filePath);
        workspace.PendEdit(new[] {filePath}, RecursionType.None, null, LockLevel.CheckOut);
    }
```

I am suspecting that this has something to do with my TFS Workspace being local. However, Visual Studio 2015 seems to have no problem establishing a lock on the file via `[Source Control Explorer]->[Right Click Selected File]->[Advanced]->[Lock]`. What am I doing that's different than what VS is doing? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I ended up implementing an event handler for  `NonFatalError` like this:

```
private static void VersionControlServer_NonFatalError(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Failure != null && e.Failure.Severity == SeverityType.Error)
            throw new ApplicationException("An internal TFS error occurred. See failure message for details:\r\n"+e.Failure.Message);
    }
```

Once the event handler was hooked up to the `versionControlServer` object via `versionControlServer.NonFatalError += VersionControlServer_NonFatalError;` I was able to see what was going on with my exclusive check-outs. As it turned out, TFS was failing **silently** with the following error:

```
TF400022: The item $/Fake/Server/Path/project.config cannot be locked for checkout in workspace MYWORKSPACE;Dan Lastname. Checkout locks are not supported in local workspaces.
```

The solution was to change the `LockLevel` from `LockLevel.CheckOut` to `LockLevel.Checkin`. Its a slightly different type of lock but its sufficient for my needs and that's the type of lock VS is using when you attempt to lock a file in a **local** workspace. So here is my original function with the tiny change in `LockLevel` that made all the difference.

```
public static void Lock(string filePath)
{
    var workspace = GetWorkspace(filePath);
    workspace.PendEdit(new[] {filePath}, RecursionType.None, null, LockLevel.Checkin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecursionType.Full not RecursionType.None.

```
workspace.PendEdit(new[] {filePath}, RecursionType.Full, null, LockLevel.CheckOut);
```

The PendEdit() method return the number of files that were checked out/locked for the filePath you specify. The RecursionType.Full will recurse to the last child of the path.

Update:
Please try to install this TFS nuget package(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) for your API project and test if this issue still exists. If it works, no matter what version of VS you use, this issue won't appear.

Comment: That still does nothing to the file in TFS - it remains unlocked and not checked-out (RecursionType setting had no effect on the result)

Comment: @Dan try to use "int count = workspace.PendEdit(new[] {filePath}, RecursionType.Full, null, LockLevel.CheckOut);" if the count is 0? Make sure there are file items under the "filePath". The filePath is a local path for your workspace.

Comment: The count is 0. The filePath is correct. PendEdit reports no errors (none that I can see at least).

Comment: @Dan could you please test the code in another machine? If the count still be 0?

Comment: Tried it on two different workstations (setup the same way as mine) - same thing (count = 0)

Comment: @Dan I have updated my reply and please check if that package works well with your project.

Comment: Installed and tested - the result did not change (count = 0)